# P4 edit not appearing to work from c# process call no error or standard output returned

Tags: c#, perforce

I am trying to checkout some files from p4 using a cmd process call from c# but the edit command does not seem to be working.  I can change the edit to the set command and get the expected results.  The edit command does not return an error or standard output.  If I put a working file path in the code I get the same result. The command works from a dos box if I type it in manually.  I am trying to do this without the p4 net.api if possible.
Is there anything I am missing in the code below?

```
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
        proc.Arguments = @" /c p4 edit";
        proc.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.UseShellExecute = false;

        using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardError)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                _threadError = result;
            }
        }
```

I have also tried passing a file in the following way and get the same result as above.  I would expect to at least get a standard error if not a standard output.

```
 string Arguments = string.Format(" //c p4 edit  -c default {0}", _tmp);
```

Comment: If P4 is a program, why you launch a CMD and then start that program? Why not to start directly the program?

Comment: You have to pass an argument to `p4 edit` specifying the file that you want to check out. Without any file name(s), `p4 edit` is going to do nothing.